# How do I set a http header variable for sending

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm building a testing tool and I need to be able to send a variable in a http request to my ingester, which should be working just fine.

The problem is it is dreadfully easy to figure out how to READ 'Accept-Monkeys: Basic capuchin; rhesus' but it like pulling teeth to find a way to SEND it...

Basically I want the PHP equivalent of the ColdFusion CFHTTPPARAM:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="http://127.0.0.1/monkeycheck" >
  <cfhttpparam name="Accept-Monkeys" type="Header" value="Basic Capuchin; Rhesus">
</cfhttp>
```

Ideally I don't want the content, I want to GO there... but if I have too, I would take a CFHTTP response and display it.

(Incidentally, this is in Drupal, if it matters, but I read [possibly inaccurately] that there is no way to do this in Drupal)

Comment: Are you using Curl, or trying to use stream wrappers?

Comment: I'm using whatever will work, the more straightforward the better.  This is just to test what some other system will be sending, so I'm more about "quick and dirty" than "robust and powerful"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://monkeymaster.com/getmonkeys.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Accept-Monkeys: Basic Capuchin; Rhesus',
  'Another-Header: yep'
));
curl_exec($ch);
```

Stream Wrapper:

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'header'=>"Accept-Monkeys: Basic Capuchin; Rhesus\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$fp = fopen('http://monkeymaster.com/getmonkeys.php', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Danke. Looks like a solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the header function.

header("Accept-Monkeys : Basic Capuchin; Rhesus");

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: If I'm not mistaken... header() is for response header codes... I need to send one on a request.